# Is it possible to pass a variable to a stored procedure call in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to do the following and I am wondering if that is possible in MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
  ulon int(4),
  usrname varchar(20),
  usrst varchar(20),
  usrdt varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE bid int(11);
START TRANSACTION; 
  SELECT t_bid INTO bid FROM generalb WHERE dt=usrdt;
INSERT 
  INTO 
    rslt
    (
       rbid,
       rusrname,
       rusrst,
       usrdt 
    ) 
  VALUES
    (
      bid,
      usrname,
      usrst,
      usrdt
    );
    call sp_nextproc_13(bid, ulon);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Look at this line:

```
call sp_nextproc_13(bid, ulon);
```

How could I achieve something like this:

call sp_nextproc_@bid(bid, ulon);

I need to be able to call a procedure dynamically as I do not know the name of the procedure until I get the bid. If anyone knows the answer, thanks so much

---

**LATEST UPDATE:**

I have made the following changes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`(
      ulon int(4),
      usrname varchar(20),
      usrst varchar(20),
      usrdt varchar(10)
    )
    BEGIN
      DECLARE bid int(11);
    START TRANSACTION; 
      SELECT t_bid INTO bid FROM generalb WHERE dt=usrdt;
    INSERT 
      INTO 
        rslt
        (
           rbid,
           rusrname,
           rusrst,
           usrdt 
        ) 
      VALUES
        (
          bid,
          usrname,
          usrst,
          usrdt
        );

        SET @sql=concat('call sp_nextproc_',bid,'(?,?)');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        SET @var1=bid;
        SET @var2=ulon;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @var1, @var2;
    COMMIT;
    END;
```

IF I hardcode some values, it works. However if I don't, it doesn't. Please see below:

If I call:

**CALL `sp_test`(2, 'John','test','AAAA');**

ERROR here:

```
SELECT t_bid INTO bid FROM generalb WHERE dt=usrdt;
```

**Column t_bid cannot be null**

If I hardcode the value like this:

```
SELECT t_bid INTO bid FROM generalb WHERE dt='AAAA';
```

The error disappears.

The second error is at the following line:

```
        SET @var1=bid;
        SET @var2=ulon;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @var1, @var2;
```

**ERROR missing value @var1 and @var2.**

If I hardcode var1 and var2, it works:

```
        SET @var1=13;
        SET @var2=2;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @var1, @var2;
```

I tried using @ and without it on the variables but that didn't work. What I am doing wrong? :(

Comment: I have never tried it. But maybe prepared statement would help. (you build the statement from a string that you can concatenate with anything you want.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    delimiter $$
    create procedure sp_test
    (
    ulon int(4)
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE bid int(11);
        set bid=8888;
...
...
...
...
        set @sql=concat('call sp_nextproc_',bid,'(?,?)');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        set @var1=bid;
        set @var2=ulon;
        EXECUTE stmt using @var1,@var2;
    END
    $$
    -- ------------
    delimiter $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_nextproc_8888`(
    IN bid int(11),
    IN ulon int(4)
    )
    BEGIN
        select bid,ulon;
    END
    $$
```

---

```
-- test with these:
-- call sp_test(9999);
-- call sp_nextproc_8888(111,222);
```

Comment: thanks drew, one question, how I include your procedure into mine? yours sounds quite advance for my SQL knowledge :(. Should I create deleteParentDownwards and then in my procedure instead of calling call call sp_nextproc_@bid(bid, ulon) should I call  call deleteParentDownwards(666);? but then how I pass (bid,ulon) values and what 666 means? Sorry it is a bit confusing how to use it :( but greatly appreciate your help thanks

Comment: take a peek at last half, i did an edit, i can't test it. not sure if execute line will work cuz i can't test too easily ! might need the var2 and var3 back with sets, someone smarter than me knows that

Comment: thank you so much Drew, I will give it a try and revert after I test it

Comment: my pleasure. i saved the most minimalist version above. you would plop the last 5 statements that are inside the BEGIN/END block into yours. That is it. Note that I could not get it to work without the `@var1` and `@var2`. That is, I could not get it to work using bid and ulon directly in the EXECUTE statement. You can get the the prior versions of this post by clicking on the Edited link, looking at a version

Comment: Hi Drew, I made a lot of testing and I just updated above my findings. Problem I still have is with getting some values :(

Comment: Correct Carol. I work with Drew who if offsite and out of pocket at the moment. Remember staring at this and that was the best workaround for that call (extensive head banging) for us at least

Comment: Hi AsConfused, thanks I will continue trying different things to see if I can figure it out how to fix it and see if someone else knows the answer. thanks a lot again.