# Stored Procedure has OUT parameter with datatype VARCHAR, would like to remove quotes of it to use it in IN clause for INT type

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

We have a stored procedure and we call it as
    `call sp_name(1, 2, @VARCHAR_TYPE_VARIABLE);`
Next we are trying to use `OUT` parameter in a `WHERE` clause like
    `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl1 WHERE FIELD_OF_TYPE_INT IN(@VARCHAR_TYPE_VARIABLE);`
But the problem is @VARCHAR_TYPE_VARIABLE has value like `'1,2,3'` (Quoted) and but my `WHERE` clause expect as `WHERE IN (1,2,3);`
My question is: how can i remove the quotes of returned `VARCHAR` `OUT` parameter to make it run for `INT` `TYPE` in `WHERE IN` clause.

Comment: This and similar questions have been asked and answered *many* times already here. The problem is that, in common with practically *all* programming languages, T-SQL doesn't take a *single* string parameter and magically decide to inspect the contents, observe that there are commas, and instead treat it as *multiple* separate parameters (possibly of a different data type). If possible, switch to using a data type *designed* for holding multiple values, such as table-valued parameters or XML. If unwilling to change, search on here (or the web) for `SQL Server split commas` and you should find.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: i am facing the issue with MySQL stored procedure, will you guidance will be same for it.

Comment: re-added your `stored-procedures` tag that you clobbered. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

This shows the treatment of an IN variable, not an out, as I was a little confused by the OUT part of what you are saying. Meaning, have an IN for an IN. If you need an OUT, give that separately. In my mind.

If you need to use other parameters inside your prepared statement, see the reference [SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) halfway down that page around the area `EXECUTE stmt2 USING @a, @b;`.

So to be clear, parameters like `@a` above are great for normal parameters one would like plugged into prepared statements (like in PHP or JAVA). The trick with yours is that lists **don't** work well in that fashion, and **require** the prepared statement string to be constructed with `concat`. One can mix and match the two. Meaning you can put one together that requires a `concat` in the part that is required, as well as execute it `USING` ... with the variables that don't require `concat`.

But here is yours.

### Schema

```
create table thingsCoveted
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null
);
insert thingsCoveted(thing) values ('Fritos'),('crackers'),('gold');
```

### Stored Proc

```
drop procedure if exists sp_name1;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure sp_name1 (
IN theList varchar(100) -- comes in like '1,3', need to strip off single quotes
)
BEGIN
    -- declare preparedSql varchar(100);
    declare theSize int;
    set theSize=length(theList);
    set @preparedSql=concat("select * from thingsCoveted where id in (",substring(theList,2,theSize-2),")");
    -- select @preparedSql; -- left here for debug view if you un-rem it
    PREPARE stmt FROM @preparedSql;
    execute stmt;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test It

```
set @var1="'1,3'"; 
call sp_name1(@var1);
+----+--------+
| id | thing  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Fritos |
|  3 | gold   |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: I appreciate your guidance, will work on it and deferentially get back to you.

Comment: Gaurav, sp's prepares are fragile in this regard. Checkout this bizarre Answer I [wrote up once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856722)