# Conditional parts of MySQL script

Tags: mysql

Sometimes I write long queries or a series of queries and save them as an SQL file to run later. Sometimes there are portions of the queries that I end up commenting out so that I can get slightly different results. I am wondering if there is some mechanism I can use directly inside a query/script to control which lines of code are run. Here is a very simple example:

```
SET @report = 1; 

SELECT
    c1,
    c2,
    c3
FROM
    table1

##if @report = 1##
WHERE
    c1 = true
    and c2 = true
GROUP BY
    c1

##if @report = 2##
WHERE
    c1 = false
    and c2 = true
GROUP BY
    c1,
    c2
;
```

*Additional Note*
I should have mentioned that most of the time these would be run from MySQL Workbench. Though it could be run from another IDE/tool.

**ANSWER**
Both Drew and Sasha Pachev gave good answers and both would be worth looking at.

1. Stored procedures
2. Prepared statements

Comment: not really. mysql isn't scriptable in this fashion. if you don't want mysql to execute a command(s), then don't feed them to mysql in the first place

Comment: @MarcB I assume this is the case but if there is something then it would be neat to find out. It could save some time. I could also do a stored procedure or actually use a programming language to build the query but again, maybe there is some trick out there that I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jam it into a stored proc. Revisit them and tweak them. Drop them. They can be your little sandboxes to use when you want.

When you use procs and functions, then if then else statements are opened up to you.

### Stored Proc

```
drop procedure if exists doTodaysThing001;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE procedure doTodaysThing001 (IN someParam INT)
BEGIN

IF (someParam=7) then
     select "seven";
     -- ...
     -- ...
END IF;

-- some other stuff

if someParam=3 then
    select "three";
END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

### Test it

```
call doTodaysThing001(3);
```

The other aspect would be prepared statements, also available inside stored procs directly, using `concat()` and binding. If you need help with that, just ask.

Comment: Here is a little reflection on the concat and bind discussion in [this answer I wrote up](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33569650)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a little trick. Using prepared statements it is possible to build queries and then execute them. Consider the following example to get started:

```
set @q:=(select "select ? + 1 as n");
prepare  s from @q;
set @a:=1;
execute s using @a;
```

The first statement generates a query (you could put tables in it combined with the results of a select), then prepare sets up statement s, then execute executes it replacing ? with the value of @a.

Comment: Prepared statements escaped my mind since I use the so infrequently. I did not know though that parameters can be passed. I will need to look into this.